# Where can I get a copy of the Rebol Flash Dialect?

Tags: flash, rebol

Searching for "Rebol Flash Dialect" on Google finds http://box.lebeda.ws/~hmm/rswf/

This used to work.  But now, visiting this page it says:

*Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /~hmm/rswf/ on this server.*

Has support been dropped?  Is there a mirror site being maintained for the code and samples of this project (which was used to make [Machinarium](http://machinarium.net/demo/))?

Comment: Rebol Tutorial: when you ask questions, please try to make it show some amount of research.  If possible work in some kind of relevance so that people who don't know any Rebol (that's most people) don't think it's so esoteric as to be a topic barely worth considering on SO.  I added a reference to Machinarium, a Rebol-driven game that even has a Wikipedia page, and showed the search terms you were probably using on Google...

Comment: Could it be you were searching for this? [http://rebol2.blogspot.de/2011/08/rebol-flash-dialect.html](http://rebol2.blogspot.de/2011/08/rebol-flash-dialect.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends, what you mean with the "support"... there was no support available, just "take it or leave it" script with a few examples... The old web page is gone, sorry, I have no time yet to move it elsewhere, but would like to. Also I still would like to update it in the future. The problem is that the dialect is using just AVM1 bytecode for scripting while today, if you want to be on mobile devices, you need AVM2. I want to examine it closer one day.

---

[11-Apr-2014/13:58:35+2:00]
**UPDATE / EDIT:**

The latest code can be found here:
https://github.com/Oldes/rs/tree/master/projects-rswf
although not as "all in one file" as it used to be.

I'm not using the SWF emitter anymore, but I still actively use the SWF parser. It's not supporting the new compression, but I don't need to parse foreign files so I'm fine with it.

At this moment I'm using the SWF parser in this script:
https://github.com/Oldes/rs/blob/master/projects-rswf/form-timeline/latest/form-timeline.r
which converts specially prepared SWF to dialect which looks like:
https://github.com/Oldes/Starling-timeline-example/blob/master/Assets/TimelineSWFs/Mlok.txt
this dialect is processed by this script:
https://github.com/Oldes/rs/tree/master/projects-rswf/pack-assets/divided
to my own binary format which I'm using in Adobe's AIR project like in this example:
https://github.com/Oldes/Starling-timeline-example

Note that the timeline-example is not updated as I don't have time on it and is not compatible with the mentioned Rebol scripts, which ARE updated to current state and used in real work.

Answer (score 1):

You can (currently!) find the latest Rebol Flash dialect source at http://rebol.desajn.net/rswf_latest.r.

Comment: it's not the latest, but one of the most up to date available

Answer (score 0):

Latest version is at https://github.com/Oldes/rs/tree/master/projects-rswf but no documentation and no support from the author ( at present ).